# Double cell if that shows #N/A, need to show a String

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have 5 cells (A,B,C,D,E). The first (A) have data, which if it has not, the second cell (B), will display #N/A. Same for the next two following cells.

What i need is, if the cells b and the cell d have #N/A, should show a string. if not, stay blank.

I manage to do it with just one cell, but i can´t get it working with two.

Cell B Formula

```
=IF(A2<>"";+INDEX('Pedidos-TR'!F:F;MATCH(A2;'Pedidos-TR'!I:I;0));"")
```

Cell D Formula

```
=IF(C2<>"";IF(SEARCHV(C2;'Pedidos-F'!B:B;1;FALSE)<>"";"Tiene Faltantes";"");"")
```

Comment: Are you looking for a formula for column E? `=IF(AND(ISNA(B2),ISNA(D2));"Your text";"")`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, use `ISNA`:

```
=IF(AND(ISNA(B2),ISNA(D2));"Your text";"")
```